# Non matching columns in two tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables they are joined by ID's, I know that there are some columns in Contract table whose data doesn't match with my warranty table even when ID's are matching. I am using the query below, does it look correct?

```
SELECT con.m_warranty_sku_id,
       con.contract_type,
       con.program_type,
       con.underwriter,
       wsk.m_warranty_sku_id,
       wsk.contract_type,
       wsk.program_type,
       wsk.sku_underwriter
FROM   mdhdba.m_contract con,
       mdhdba.m_warranty_sku wsk
WHERE  ( wsk.m_warranty_sku_id = con.m_warranty_sku_id )
       AND con.contract_type <> wsk.contract_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct as solution, i adjusted your query in order to explicit my join

```
SELECT con.m_warranty_sku_id,
       con.contract_type,
       con.program_type,
       con.underwriter,
       wsk.m_warranty_sku_id,
       wsk.contract_type,
       wsk.program_type,
       wsk.sku_underwriter
FROM   mdhdba.m_contract con innerjoin mdhdba.m_warranty_sku wsk
ON wsk.m_warranty_sku_id = con.m_warranty_sku_id
WHERE  con.contract_type <> wsk.contract_type
```

Answer (score 0):

The above query can not handle NULL coulmns. If there are more than one row with m_warranty_sku_id than also it will give trouble.

Do like this
1. Handle NULL exclusively if there are null values for join.
2. You may use MINUS and UNION clause to separate out not matching m_warranty_sku_id and join tables only for those values.